# visual studio 2017 addin Object Exporter install not complete

Tags: object, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-addins, exporter

I installed addin **Object Exporter**,
and the installation picture as below

[installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh73X.png)

I wait a lot of time for the installation to complete,
but the install not completed!

Answer (score 1):

From the processes list I see you have Microsoft Visual Studio running. You should manually close all instances of Visual Studio before installing any VS 2017 extension.